# Remove/disable HTML ELEMENT dropdown selector from Gutenberg block editor

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am struggling to disable/remove the HTML ELEMENT dropdown selector from the WordPress Gutenberg block editor from the group/row block from the advance tab.
Is it even possible to remove this dropdown selector?
[Screenshot of the setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrrsJ.png)

This setting is coming from this file
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/group/edit.js

Any guidance or help will be appreciated.

I have tried using the register block filter. Also, tried setting the html attribute to false.

Comment: Relevant, simplified code should be posted in your question, not on an external site. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then [edit] your question.